# hasOneThrough() relationship is giving "BadMethodCallException, Call to undefined method [name of model]::hasOneThrough()"

Tags: laravel

I have a simple relationship of one subfamily which has many genera, each of which has many species.

So:

Species has one Subfamily through Genus.
Subfamily has many Species through Genus.

```
class Species extends Model
{
    /** Return the many-to-one relationship with the Genus model.
     * 
     * @return App\Models\Genus
     */
    public function genus()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Genus::class);
    }

    /** Return the one-to-one relationship with the Subfamily model through the Genus model.
     * 
     * @return App\Models\Subfamily
     */
    public function subfamily()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Subfamily::class, Genus::class);
    }

}

class Genus extends Model
{
    /** Returns the one-to-many relationship with the Species class
     * 
     * @return App\Models\Species
     */
    public function species()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Species::class);
    }

    /** Returns the many-to-one relationship with the Subfamily class
     * 
     * @return App\Models\Subfamily
     */
    public function subfamily()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subfamily::class);
    }
}

class Subfamily extends Model
{

    /** Returns the one-to-many relationship with the Genus class
     * 
     * @return App\Models\Genus
     */
    public function genera()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Genus::class);
    }

    /** Returns the one-to-many relationship with the Species class through the Genus class
     * 
     * @return App\Models\Genus
     */
    public function species()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Species::class, Genus::class);
    }
}
```

Trying it in tinker gives me:

```
>>> $species->subfamily
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method App/Models/Species::hasOneThrough()'
```

But somehow using the hasManyThrough() in the $subfamily->species relation works fine though!

Comment: Which laravel version are you using? Has one through has been introduced in Laravel 5.8

Comment: Oh that might be it. I'm using 5.7

Comment: I posted that as an answer so you can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upgrade to Laravel `5.8` to use `hasOneThrough()`. I hope that helps! Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Which laravel version are you using?
Has one through has been introduced in Laravel 5.8